# Ask for help on proving irreducible polynomial on $K[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field and $a,b\in F$ with $a\ne0$. Then, $f(x)\in F[x]$ is irreducible if and only if $f(ax+b)\in F[x]$ is irreducible.

This is my proof

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $f(x)=h(x)g(x)$ is irreducible with $h(x),g(x)\in K[x]$, then $f(ax+b)=h(ax+b)g(ax+b)$. Because $f(x)$ is irreducible, then $h(x)\ne0$ or $g(x)\ne0$, then $h(ax+b)\ne0$ or $g(ax+b)\ne0$. So $f(ax+b)$ is irreducible.
$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $f(ax+b)$ is irreducible, let $y=ax+b\in F$, then for every $c,d\in F$ with $c\ne0$, $f(cy+d)$ is irreducible. Put $c=a^{-1}$ and $b=-(a^{-1}b)$, we have $f(cy+d)=f(a^{-1}ax+a^{-1}b-a^{-1}b)=f(x)$.

Please let me know if i made any mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: "…then $h(x) \neq 0$ or $g(x) \neq 0$…" doesn’t have to do with (ir)reducibility. An element $f$ of a ring is irreducible if whenever we write $f = hg$ at least one of $h$ or $g$ is a **unit** in the ring (a divisor of $1$). It happens that the units in the polynomial ring $F[x]$ are exactly the nonzero constants $F^\times$, so irreducibility here means that in any factorization at least one of the factors is a **nonzero constant**.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is irreducible, then the only possible factorization $f(x)=h(x)g(x)$ is w.l.o.g $h(x)=c$ constant and $g(x)$ some irreducible. So by writing $f(x)=h(x)g(x)$, you've shifted the problem from showing that $f(ax+b)$ is irreducible, to $g(ax+b)$ is irreducible. And in general, not having a root does not imply irreducibilty, e.g $(x^2+1)^2\in\mathbb{Q[x]}$. So you should be a bit more careful with your forward implication.

Comment: Hint: The map $p(x)  \mapsto p(ax+b)$ is a ring automorphism of $K[x]$. (Finds its inverse!)